# Load and execute page (HTML, Javascript) without displaying the graphics (Xcode)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm using a UIWebView to display a page from a particular URL. I execute a javascript to parse all the info I need and I have to keep the UIWebView in case the page content changes.

The problem is that UIWebview uses a lot of resources to display the HTML and CSS, is there a way to keep the HTML and JavaScript being executed without processing the resulting page into graphics (simply hiding it won't work, it will use the same amount of memory)? Or is there another solution that could be used instead of a UiWebview?

Comment: I get an idea but then I realise that problem is that graphics can be loaded from both, the html and css. While you could use if (! <img src) for the html ,for the css would be more tricky...some divs have  background images, and you should catch them as well.

Comment: The whole idea is that I mimic the website in the app, thus reconstructing it from the data I capture from the website. The thing is that I don't want the uiwebview to process the received HTML/CSS into graphical output. I just want the raw HTML/Javascript work without the need to display them.

Comment: You should then strip all html tags, and use the text only. However to do that, you will have to create some kind of layout that to look nice and not just bunch of text. Hopefully the content will not have tables bullet lists etc...

Comment: don't load it into a webview: ajax in the html and use a document fragment to dissect the markup.

Comment: @dandavis could you explain how to accomplish that? Also consider that the user has to login, so it has to save cookies along

Comment: It depends on the web page you works on. If it is just a static web page, you can extract what you want easily without showing it. But if it is a dynamic page that use ajax request to load data, parse the data and show the data in some way, it maybe better for you to read the js logic of how to do this and do it in your own way.

Comment: @xi.lin What happens is that once the page is loaded I attach jQuery script to the page. Then I load a jQuery script (using "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString") that parses the info from tags with particular classes and attributes and sends back to the app as a JSON. It all goes smoothly, but the uiwebview uses too much memory. Also the JavaScript was probably obfuscated since I can barely understand the meaning of a single JavaScript function, so going through the pain of figuring out how the ajax is sent is not worth the effort.

Comment: What you need is to get the DOM tree. But it seems that the only way to get it is using UIWebView. If you stop the loading of images, I believe the cost is acceptable. Be sure to create a small frame size of UIWebView, which help to reduce the resource occupation.